# Can I use lambda if the abstract class has more than 1 method in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

For example if I this piece of code compiler is suggesting to change to

```
private val viewListener = object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        toast("View clicked!$v")
    }
}
```

following code

```
private val viewListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
    toast("View clicked!$v")
}
```

but if I have this abstract class

```
public abstract class DrawableCallback implements Callback {

    public void onLoaded() {}

    public void onError() {}

    public static int extractDrawable() {}

    public abstract void onDrawableExtracted(int color);
}
```

and I use it here

```
private val drawableCallback = object : DrawableCallback() {
    override fun onDrawableExtracted(color: Int) {
      //...
    }
}
```

Here it seems I can't convert to lambda , can you explain why?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html?_ga=2.130240463.192967285.1587913221-2062417670.1570701915#sam-conversions

Comment: @Michael So it doesn't work for abstract classes ,yes?

Comment: Incidentally, your abstract class might as well be an interface with default implementations for all but one of the methods, and then it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot use it with abstract classes**. Refer to Kotlin Lang [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html?_ga=2.130240463.192967285.1587913221-2062417670.1570701915#sam-conversions) (also in comments by Michael). It states clearly:

> Note that SAM conversions only work for interfaces, not for abstract
>   classes, even if those also have just a single abstract method.

. If you need to know more (like in why not?), refer to this discussion [Why can't @FunctionalInterface be applied to a SAM abstract base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482093/why-cant-functionalinterface-be-applied-to-a-sam-abstract-base-class). This discussion is around Java, but equally applies to Kotlin on JVM for obvious reasons.

Comment: I understand it works only for interfaces with 1 method, but there is way to make it work if interface >1 method ,yes 
if the Java class has multiple methods taking functional interfaces, you can choose the one you need to call by using an adapter function that converts a lambda to a specific SAM type. Those adapter functions are also generated by the compiler when needed
But I don't understand how I can do this?